# Objective-C runtime crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I am trying out Objective-C runtime methods for the first time. I have been reading a chapter(24) on this from iOS 7 programming pushing the limits. As per the example in the book I have implemented a message dispatcher function which is as below:

```
static const void *myMsgSend(id receiver, const char *name) {
    SEL selector = sel_registerName(name);
    Class receiverClass = object_getClass(receiver);
    IMP methodIMP = class_getMethodImplementation(receiverClass, selector);
    return CFBridgingRetain(methodIMP(receiver, selector));
}
```

I test this dispatcher in the function below:

```
void runMyMsgSend() {
    // NSObject *object = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    Class class = (Class)objc_getClass("NSObject");
    id object = class_createInstance(class, 0);
    myMsgSend(object, "init");

    // id description = [object description];
    id description = (__bridge id)myMsgSend(object, "description");

    // const char *cstr = [description UTF8String];
    const char *cstr = myMsgSend(description, "UTF8String");

    printf("---------------------");
    printf("%s\n", cstr);
}
```

The function works well for **init** and **description** for object instance of type **NSObject**.
When the dispatcher function is called on object pointed by *description* with *UTF8String* as the method to run it crashes on

> return CFBridgingRetain(methodIMP(receiver, selector));

Now I know that NSString is a cluster and actually an object of __NSCFString is used. I think this may be the problem while calling **CFBridgingRetain**. I need a better understanding of what is actually causing the crash. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call `CFBridgingRetain` on all return types..

The documentation explicitly states that if the `IMP` returns anything that is NOT `void`, then you must explicitly cast it to the right function pointer type.

Your function is:

```
static const void *myMsgSend(id receiver, const char *name) {
    SEL selector = sel_registerName(name);
    Class receiverClass = object_getClass(receiver);
    IMP methodIMP = class_getMethodImplementation(receiverClass, selector);
    id (*imp)(id, SEL) = (id (*)(id, SEL))methodIMP;
    return CFBridgingRetain(imp(receiver, selector));
}
```

When you called `UTF8String`, it returns a `const char*` which you are trying to retain. Not only that, but you are saying that the `IMP` returns an `id` and you retain that.. You can only retain Objective-C class objects. You never casted to the correct function pointer type so it crashes trying to implicitly convert `const char*` to `id`..

Therefore your method needs to be:

```
static const void *myMsgSend(id receiver, const char *name) {
    SEL selector = sel_registerName(name);
    Class receiverClass = object_getClass(receiver);
    IMP methodIMP = class_getMethodImplementation(receiverClass, selector);

    void* (*imp)(id, SEL) = (void* (*)(id, SEL))methodIMP;
    return imp(receiver, selector, args);
}
```

where it returns a simple `void*` which can be NULL or BOOL or int or w/e type (primitive).. If it needed to return an object, the object is implicitly bridged so no need to retain (just cast the result to the right type).

However, it is probably a much better idea to use `NSInvocation` as the implementation of this function because then you don't have to worry about type and arguments and so on..

Comment: Correct up until the enhanced bit.    Varargs don't work like that.  You can't pass `args` as a parameter and have it work with a non-vararg method or function.

Comment: @Brandon That was helpful. Wouldn't have solved it without your help. The type cast of IMP to a functionpointer returning void* is crucial.

Comment: @bbum Thanks for your thoughts. I will take into consideration your point on varargs.